# Timer not calling the repeat function in my windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service, timer

My code is as follows:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{  

            //Set the interval of timer to 5 minutes.
            timer1.Interval = 300000;
            //Enable the timer.
            timer1.Enabled = true;

          repeatFunction();
}
```

And i called the repeat function inside my timer_tick event as follows:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     eventLog1.WriteEntry("Timer ticked");

                 repeatFunction();            
}
```

But the timer is not ticking. Any body please tell me where did i went wrong..

Comment: Which timer and where are you declaring the timer?

Comment: Timer dragged from the toolbox after creating the windows service..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is like this : check it

How to use Timer class to raise an event after certain interval?

```
timer1.Interval = 5000;
timer1.Enabled = true;
timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler (OnTimerEvent);
```

Write the event handler

This event will be executed after every 5 secs.

```
public static void OnTimerEvent(object source, EventArgs e)
{
m_streamWriter.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
m_streamWriter.Flush();
}
```

also check this property ]

**AutoReset**

Indicates whether the Timer raises the Tick event each time the specified Interval has elapsed or whether the Tick event is raised only once after the first interval has elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the timer1_Tick method to the timer Elapsed event.

```
        timer.Interval = 300000;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer.Start();
```